Is there a name for the $C^*$–subalgebra fixed by a projection?
Let $A$ be a $C^*$–algebra and let $p$ be a projection, ie. $p^2=p=p^*.$ Consider
$$\{a\in A: ap=pa=a\}\;.$$ Assuming I haven't made a mistake, this is a $C^*$–subalgebra. Does it have a name?

The set
$$
\{a \in A : ap = pa = a\}
$$
is known as the corner associated with the projection $p$. It is a $C^*$–subalgebra of $A$ and is denoted by $pAp$. This set consists of all elements of $A$ that are 'localized' to the range of the projection $p$.

"is denoted by $pAp$" is not precise. This notation has a different meaning, a priori, and it is a little lemma that they are the same.
